# Is there a way to prevent an iframe sandbox from sending postMessages?

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox, postmessage

Let's say I have an Iframe with the attribute `sandbox="allow-scripts"`.

I might or might not be in control of the page loading that iframe.
Is there any possibility how to prevent the iframe from sending postMessages other than overwriting the parents postMessage function - which I might not be able to do if the parent is not my domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague came up with an idea. One can sum it up with: make the parent part of your domain so that you can overwrite its postMessage method.

If it is not possible to control the top window containing the iframe, why not put the original iframe within another iframe. The additional frame-layer can act as a firewall. By overwriting the postMessage-Method of that intermediate firewall-iframe one can make sure that the original iframe can postMessage whatever it wants but the firewall-iframe only forwards incomming messages that are wished to be postable.

Of course this comes with some constraints as to what has to be the destination domain of the postMessage-call.

Comment: how did you do this? I tried and it is not working. I have tried to have every layer overwrite postMessage and browsers ignore it or if of parent/top complains it is not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just check the read-only [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/source) property of the MessageEvent.

```html
<iframe src="evil.html" class="ignore-messages"></iframe>
<iframe src="safe.html"></iframe>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(e)
{
    // Blacklist messages if e.source matches iframe.ignore-messages
    if(Array.from(document.querySelector('iframe.ignore-messages'))
            .map(f => f.contentWindow)
            .indexOf(e.source) !== -1
      ) return;
    
    // handle message from safe.html
    // this message cannot come from evil.html,
    // since that iframe has the class "ignore-messages"
};
```

Other ways to achieve this are through a whitelist such as:

```js
// allow only from parent
if(e.source !== parent) return;
```

```js
// allow only from a given set of iframes
if(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('iframe.accept-messages')).map(f => f.contentWindow).indexOf(e.source) === -1) return;
```

The advantage of a whitelist over a blacklist, is that the iframe which sent a message may not be in the DOM-tree anymore, or the classList may have been changed, etc. Which is more common when working with dynamic HTML generated by javascript. Therefore, using a whitelist is a foolproof approach.